# Android http request blocked by incapsula

Tags: android, httprequest, incapsula

In my app i have been using DefaultHttpClient to send HttpRequest with a user agent (to get full site) to a news website.
It seems recently the website started using Incapsula, and i get this now:

```
<iframe src="/_Incapsula_Resource?CWUDNSAI=9_1008B529&incident_id=48000040010778737-143658980947787847&edet=12&cinfo=5688c053c753829330000000" frameborder=0 width="100%" height="100%" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px">Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident ID: 48000040010778737-143658980947787847</iframe></html>
```

Any hints ? Can i bypass incapusla ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

I work for Incapsula and I think I can help out.

Incapsula security platform offers various customization options. As a result, each of our clients can harden the default settings, modify existing security rules and add additional filtering policies.

I can't say if you've been blocked by our default or by site-specific settings. One way or another, you can always reach out the site's operator who can whitelist you with a click of a button.

GL

Comment: thanks for the reply. how do incapsula detect that the request is comingfrom a smartphone ? is the mac or user-agent, etc.. ?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delayed response. We have a complete signature directory, based on Header order and values. We also have a challenge system, which I can't fully disclose, which we use for un-recognized  signatures. Of course, all of the regular reputation based methods will also apply.

Comment: Im having a similar issue and was wondering if you ended up white listing some Google plus ip's and possible where i could find the ip ranges. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, sure you can use http://botopedia.org to verify specific IP addresses. However, if you are looking for a list of ranges, I don't think they officially provide that and we can't share our full lists (per company policy)

Comment: Hi, We are also facing the same problem, if anyone can explain how to whitelist android app request? Thank you

Comment: Same problem here.  Incapsula incident ID: 84000060020984977-20005364964786282 from a website checking script.  The poor restaurant is not helped by this blocking.