# How to re-order HTTP headers?

Tags: linux, nginx, http-headers, mitmproxy

I was wondering if there was any way to **re-order HTTP headers** that are being sent by our browser, before getting sent back to the web server?

Since the order of the headers leaves some kind of "fingerprinting", see [this post](https://www.prxbx.com/forums/showthread.php?tid=1865) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30787664/can-servers-use-http-headers-order-to-catch-a-browser-signature), I was thinking about using **MITMProxy** (with Inline Scripting, I guess) to modify headers on-the-fly.  Is this possible?

How would one achieve that?
Note: I'm looking for a method that could be scripted, not a method using a graphical tool like the *Burp Suite* (although Burp is known to be able to re-order headers)

I'm open to suggestions.  Perhaps NGINX might come to the rescue as well?

EDIT: I should be more specific, by giving an example...

Let's say I'm using Firefox.  With the use of a funky add-on, I'm spoofing my user-agent to "look" like a Chrome browser.  But then if I test my browser with [ip-check.info](http://ip-check.info/), the "signature" of my browser remains the one of Firefox, even though my spoofed user-agent shows "Chrome".

So the solution, in this specific case, should be to re-order the HTTP headers in the same manner as Chrome does.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

For the record, the order of the HTTP headers *should* not matter at all according to [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2.2). But now that you have asked... this can be done in mitmproxy as follows:

```
import random

def request(context, flow):
    # flow.request.headers.fields is a tuple of (name, value) header tuples.
    h = list(flow.request.headers.fields)
    random.shuffle(h)
    flow.request.headers.fields = tuple(h)
```

See the mitmproxy documentation on [netlib.http.Headers](http://docs.mitmproxy.org/en/latest/dev/models.html#netlib.http.Headers) for more details.

There are tons of way to reorder them as you wish:

```
def reorder(headers, header_order=["Host","User-Agent","Accept"]):
    lines = []
    for name in header_order:  # add existing headers in the specified order
        if name in headers:
            lines.extend(headers.get_all(name))
            del headers[name]
    lines.extend(headers.fields)  # all other headers
    return lines
request.headers.fields = reorder(request.headers)
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  But I've edited my question to be more specific (What if I want to order the headers, exactly as I want them?)  I guess [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31205415/how-to-capture-http-request-response-headers-with-mitmproxy?rq=1) might be a good start?

Comment: `headers.fields` is just the list of headers as they will be sent on the wire, you can rearrange them as you wish. I added a small example above.

Comment: Thanks Maximilian, I'm gonna try your piece of code, this week-end.  Do you think I can save your script as-is (obviously after adding more headers) into a .py file, and it will be ready to be "loaded" into MITMproxy?  Anything else needed?  (I say this because, I'm a total noob, when it comes to Python)

Comment: `NameError: name 'request' is not defined` : This is the error message I get, when I try to load this mini-script.  Perhaps we're missing something here?  I am on Python 3.5.1

Comment: Your help would be very appreciated...  Should I add an import line or a "from" line at the beginning of the script?

Comment: How to integrate the mitmproxy with the browser? By defining a proxy to the browser and routing the network through it? Is there a way to change the order of the headers by creating a custom browser extension instead of a proxy?