# Nginx response header order

Tags: nginx, server, http-headers, webserver

Is it possible to change the order of the response headers?

If its:

1.Server

2.Date

3.X-Powered-By

And I want to order it like this:

1.Date

2.X-Powered-By

3.Server

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you want to change the order? The order is not important for headers with different names. It's only when you have 2 or more headers with the same name that the order matters.

Comment: @StefanOS I want to make it act like an existing server, and with nginx the order is different.

Comment: Ok. As far as I know this cannot be done in nginx but you can add middleware like mitmproxy to do this. Check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37341273/how-to-re-order-http-headers

Comment: @StefanOS Thank you, ill try that.

Comment: Ill be happy if someone can point out a way to do that with nginx.